# Conceal not working with tex files and vim-plug

Tags: filetype-tex, conceal, plugin-vim-plug

Normally, `:syn match Entity "e" conceal` and `:set conceallevel=3` results in all `e`s being concealed.  But, if I use vim-plug, this does not work in a tex-file …

Comment: How do you *use* it? You wash the car? :D

Comment: @VanLaser, if you are asking what plugins I loaded, I tried commenting out all. It is plug-vim itself that causes the problem.

Comment: Try to put those lines in (possibly new) `~/.vim/after/syntax/tex.vim`

Comment: @VanLaser, already tried that, it didn't work.

Comment: Create an issue on `vim-plug` github page, and make sure you include a minimal vimrc that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Check the syn rules for your tex file.